# Hibernate makes additional SELECT for every missing FK

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Imagine this data model:

```
@Entity
@Data
public class A {

    @Id
    long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn
    @NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
    B b;
}

@Entity
@Data
public class B {

    @Id
    long id;
}
```

Now imagine the following data (and yes, it is inconsistent in the DB):

```
A
  id | b_id
  ---------
  1  | 1
  2  | 2

B
  id
  ---
  1
```

As you see, A#2 has FK to B#2 which is actually missing.

That makes Hibernate execute an additional SELECT request to check if it is actually missing, though it has already found that out while making a SELECT A LEFT JOIN B request. Is it possible somehow to prevent this additional request from being executed?

That's what happens when I fetch A#1:

```
2018-01-17 18:43:05.545 DEBUG 5332 --- [           main] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select a0_."id" as id1_0_0_, a0_."b_id" as b_id2_0_0_, b1_."id" as id1_1_1_ from TEST.A a0_ left outer join TEST.B b1_ on a0_."b_id"=b1_."id" where a0_."id"=?
2018-01-17 18:43:05.555 TRACE 5332 --- [           main] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - [1]
2018-01-17 18:43:05.561 TRACE 5332 --- [           main] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor   : extracted value ([id1_1_1_] : [BIGINT]) - [1]
2018-01-17 18:43:05.565 TRACE 5332 --- [           main] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor   : extracted value ([b_id2_0_0_] : [BIGINT]) - [1]
```

And that's for A#2:

```
2018-01-17 18:42:13.597 DEBUG 5283 --- [           main] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select a0_."id" as id1_0_0_, a0_."b_id" as b_id2_0_0_, b1_."id" as id1_1_1_ from TEST.A a0_ left outer join TEST.B b1_ on a0_."b_id"=b1_."id" where a0_."id"=?
2018-01-17 18:42:13.605 TRACE 5283 --- [           main] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - [2]
2018-01-17 18:42:13.611 TRACE 5283 --- [           main] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor   : extracted value ([id1_1_1_] : [BIGINT]) - [null]
2018-01-17 18:42:13.615 TRACE 5283 --- [           main] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor   : extracted value ([b_id2_0_0_] : [BIGINT]) - [2]
2018-01-17 18:42:13.617 DEBUG 5283 --- [           main] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select b0_."id" as id1_1_0_ from TEST.B b0_ where b0_."id"=?
2018-01-17 18:42:13.617 TRACE 5283 --- [           main] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - [2]
```

Comment: Why not put valid data in the database in the first place, and use proper FOREIGN KEYs? (which would prevent invalid data being inserted)

Comment: Good point, but the database is read-only and provided by a customer, so the only way to make it valid is copying it to our own database, which is a bit of an overkill.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a `JOIN FETCH` in your query instead of a simple `JOIN`. The default behavior for `@ManyToOne` associations is to be eager, unless you specify it to be LAZY, so I don't know why is it happening. Anyway, the fetch join should solve it.

Comment: Actually I tried different approaches including HQL with JOIN FETCH and @NamedEntityGraph, but was not able to solve this.

Comment: To make the question more clear, B#1 is correctly fetched without any additional SELECTs. It is just that B#2 (which is missing and so was not JOINed) is requested once again.

Comment: Try this: specify the association metadata as `optional=true` in the @ManyToOne column and use the annotation @JoinColumn with `nullable=true`

Comment: Nope :( Btw I believe optional=true / nullable=true are actually defaults.

Comment: When exatcly is hibernate issuing the extra select? When you call the getter  to get the association?

Comment: I just call aRepository.findOne(2L) or EM.find(A.class, 2L). I've added logs to the original question so you can see requests more clearly.

Comment: @MikhailKadan you could try one final solution, which is to use `@Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)`. However, if `JOIN FETCH` didn't help, I doubt this will work, either. It seems that once the query for `A` is made, Hibernate moves to initializing non-lazy associations, and an `A.b` with a missing `B`, though with a foreign key present, is still regarded as uninitialized at that point.

Comment: Yep, unfortunately didn't help either.